java error for android app (error: cannot find symbol of package which already imported)
I published an app on google play after 4 months when I came back for starting update, it cannot run, this is my question why after passing 4 months this error created while I did not do anything in this time.
the error is in java file and about "error: cannot find symbol import androidx.multidex.MultiDex;" also "error: cannot find symbol
MultiDex.install(this);
^
symbol:   variable MultiDex
location: class FlutterMultiDexApplication"
that errors the complete messages are :
F:\virtual Painting Studio\nani's tetris\nani_tetris_game-101\Copy_nani_tetris_game\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\app\FlutterMultiDexApplication.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
import androidx.multidex.MultiDex;
^
symbol:   class MultiDex
location: package androidx.multidex
F:\virtual Painting Studio\nani's tetris\nani_tetris_game-101\Copy_nani_tetris_game\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\app\FlutterMultiDexApplication.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
MultiDex.install(this);
^
symbol:   variable MultiDex
location: class FlutterMultiDexApplication
2 errors
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.


Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 56s
I try to flutter clean, flutter run but these orders could not help me.
I changed minSdkVersion to 23 in build gradle but it could not fix

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
